# Connection to MongoDB with SSH in my Node App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh, digital-ocean

My DB is with DigitalOcean and I'm trying to connect to it in my node app.

I've found a npm called `tunnel-ssh` however am having trouble connecting to it. My code is below.

It says DB connection successful, however when i do a `console.log(mongoose)` it shows the host and host as null.

If I do `console.log(mongoose)`, after the `console.log("DB connection successful");` then it shows me the host.

```
var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');

var config = {
    agent : 'myuser',
    host: 'xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx'
    agent : process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
    privateKey:require('fs').readFileSync('id_rsa'),
    port:22,
    dstPort:27010,
    keepAlive: true
};

var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {

    if(error){
        console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
    }

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mysuperdb');

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
        console.log("DB connection successful");
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you sure your ssh key is properly required?

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean? The SSH key is valid, if thats the question.

Comment: Yes! I know its valid, I just want you to check if you are getting it properly.

Comment: Yes, its getting it properly

Answer (score 6):

Here's the working code:

```
var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');

var config = {
    username : 'myuser',
    host: 'xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx',
    privateKey:require('fs').readFileSync('id_rsa'),
    port:22,
    dstPort:27010,
    localPort: 2000
};

var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {

    if(error){
        console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
    }

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:2000/mysuperdb');

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
        console.log("DB connection successful");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ports aren't matching up. You have `dstPort: 27010` but your connection string is `'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mysuperdb'`. One or the other needs to be corrected.

Comment: When using that same dstPort 27017, i get the error `EADDRINUSE` - which i understand is because that port is being used on my local machine.

Comment: So you have a MongoDB installation on both the same host as the script *and* remotely on another server (that you're accessing over ssh)? If so, you will need to add `localPort` to your config and set it to some unused port and use that port in your MongoDB connection string.

Comment: I think i got it. So yes Mongo is also running locally on the default 27017 port hence I was getting the EADDRINUSE error. So when i stop MongoDB on my local machine, it works fine. However is it possible to say connect to x port on the remote, but locally, pass through y port?

Comment: Yes, add the config option I just mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I attempted that but I still got the ECONNREFUSED - I'm wondering whether its because the localPort: 2000 is already in use? Otherwise, to make life easier, shall i just change the port the local MongoDB is using. I install MongoDB through homebew, but assume the config is in the usual `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`. Then do i just stop and start it again?

Comment: All good now, I finally got working. I simply forgot to update the mongoose connection URL as well. i.e. if `localPort: 2000`, then I also had to update `mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:2000/mysuperdb');` Of course, the dstPort, is the actual MongoDB port I'm connecting to.